# React component doesn't rerender with the same props but child state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have the following problem:
I have parent component (where is button, and array of child components to render).

To each child i pass props and child uses it as state, then changes it.
The problem is that children doesn't rerender.

As it may seem not understandable, here is something more clear (i hope):

Here is the simplified version of child.js

```
export default function ChildComponent(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(props.open);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  }; /* i actually never use handleClick */

  const handleClose = (event) => {
    setOpen(open => !open);
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <SomeComponent hideAfterTimeMs={1000} onClose={handleClose}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Parent:

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./demo";

class MyClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      something: false,
    };
  }

  displayKids = () => {
    const a = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      a.push(<Child open={true} key={i} message={"Abcd " + i} />);
    }
    return a; 
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      something: !prevState.something,
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleChange}>Nacisnij mnie</button>
        {this.displayKids()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MyClass;
```

So basically the child component renders,
and sets its "open" to false,
and when i click button again
i hoped for displaying child again,
but nothing happens.

Child renders something that disappears after a few seconds.

Comment: That is what your code does, so seems expected. Can you be more specific about what isn't working? What button is being clicked? So after the child auto hides after a timeout, what is supposed to re-open it?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Basically i want to render the same component many times (where the components disappears after specific amount time, that's why when i click i want it to render again). To be more specific I click button in parent component (there is only one there) and then i want to display children with displayKids method. The button changes some state so i thought this will cause rerender but its not working that way.

Comment: What child component does is when "open" is "true" then something (like some text) is displayed, and after specific amount of time(like 1000ms) handleClose is called and "open" is changed to "false". So from parent i pass the variable open={true} and childs uses this for initial state (from props)

Comment: Please provide a working snippet.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ziucp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like your components are linked in any meaningful way. Clicking the button on the `My Class` component updates the `something` state, but that state is not passed to the `Child` component.

Similarly, the `SomeComponent` component handles its own close, and tells the `Child` component it is closed via `handleClose` - but that is not communicated to the parent and neither does the parent or `Child` communicate any open state to `SomeComponent`.

Changing some state on `Child` will not rerender it's own children. Something new has to be passed as a prop for that to happen.

Comment: Okay, maybe i tell a bit more. I have a form and onSubmit i run validate function. In validate function if some field is wrong i add this field name to "erorrs" array which is in the state. So for example errors = ["name", "address"]. And then in displayKids I iterate over errors array and give the elements of the errors array as props to Children. So when the submit button is clicked again without changing any fields in form then errors array is the same and kids dont render.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ziucp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I've been working on my own codesandbox in the meantime ;) I have simplified things quite a bit because I'm still not sure you're getting how the prop>state>prop cycle works in react. Please take a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-fog-mbvzy).

Comment: Okay, i was able to change it for implementation to my code and it works. You can paste it (link to sandbox?) as your answer and i will mark it as right one. Thanks so much ! :)

Comment: This is not correct. If you will provide a new unique key, e.g. key={new Date()} it will re-render. See https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-fxloe for a working example (only change is key prop).

Comment: Fair enough, that does also work. It doesn't invalidate what I said though, you are still changing a prop to force a rerender. I'm not sure generating random keys is a good solution at scale.

Answer (score 1):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are
>   removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give
>   the elements a stable identity.

You are using the index as a key. Please try to use a unique key. E.g. child id or random hash code.

If the key is unique and new it will re-render. Right now it is not re-rendering because the key is the same.

Check out: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: sure, but... it doesn't change anything ;)

Comment: It solves the issue. Please try in your code sandbox. You just changed i to i.toString(), but "1" still equals "1". Please changes to something unique, e.g. key={new Date()}. If you have a unique key it will re-render. If it will have the same key it will not rerender. See: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-fxloe

Comment: Ohh so it has to be new key each time to render? :o

Comment: If it has a new key it will be rendered (again). Otherwise it will only re-render if props change, but you don't always have props you can or want to change.